# Boundary condition Hamiltonian with point tinteractions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I`m studying the Hamiltonian with point interaction centered in $y$ in three dimensions.
I know that the elements in the domain of the Hamiltonian are of the form
$$\psi=\phi+qG^z(\cdot-y)$$
where $G^z(x)=\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z}|x|}}{4\pi|x|}$, $q\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi\in H^2$. The boundary condition is
$$q=\frac{4\pi\phi(y)}{4\pi\alpha-i\sqrt{z}}$$
Many times it is written in the form
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\bigg[\frac{\partial (r\psi)}{\partial r}-4\pi\alpha(r\psi)\bigg]=0$$.
Are these two relations equivalent?

Comment: There are some misprints in your post. To get replies, you should be a lot more explicit, I guess.

Comment: What misprints?